# local collection types not allowed in SQL statements - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    type r05_id_type is TABLE  of r01_table.R01_ID%TYPE;

    r01_ids r05_id_type;
BEGIN

SELECT r1.r01_ID as R01_ID
BULK COLLECT INTO r01_ids
FROM r01_table r1, r05_table r5
WHERE r1.r01_ID= r5.r05_R01_ID_FK
AND r5.r05_status='D' AND  r5.r05_date_time_captured <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1095 
AND r1.r01_id NOT IN(select r01.r01_ID
                FROM r01_table r01, r05_table r05
                WHERE r05.r05_status !='D'
                AND r01.r01_ID= r05.r05_R01_ID_FK);

  dbms_output.put_line(r01_ids.COUNT);

  FOR indx IN 1 .. r01_ids.COUNT
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(r01_ids(indx));
     insert all into r01_table_archived (R01_ID_TYPE,R01_IDENTITY_NUMBER,R01_PASSPORT_COUNTRY,R01_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED)
     values(rr1_R01_ID_TYPE,rr1_R01_IDENTITY_NUMBER,rr1_R01_PASSPORT_COUNTRY,rr1_R01_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED)
     select rr1_R01_ID_TYPE,rr1_R01_IDENTITY_NUMBER,rr1_R01_PASSPORT_COUNTRY,rr1_R01_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED
     FROM (SELECT R01_ID_TYPE,R01_IDENTITY_NUMBER,R01_PASSPORT_COUNTRY,R01_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED
            FROM r01_table
            WHERE r01_id IN (r01_ids));
  END LOOP;

END;
```

I am writing the above procedure in order to check some records between two tables and storing the matching ID (`r01_ID`) in an inner table call `r01_ids`. 
`dbms_output.put_line(r01_ids(indx))` prints the correct values which indicates that the values are correctly inserting to `r01_ids`.
but the issue happens when I try to insert the values to the  r01_table_archived table within the LOOP.

I am getting the below error

> PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Can't I get the values of `r01_ids` from the insert query like this? If I am wrong, someone please help me to find what's the issue and how to perform it in the right way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until `Oracle 11g`, if you declare `type` under the scope of a PLSQL block, it cannot be called in `SQL` statement within the block and this is the reason you are getting this error:

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

You can create a type outside the `SCOPE` of `PLSQL` block and then use it in `SQL`. See below:

```
--Created a type of Number assuming ID is number
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE R05_ID_TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/
--Block
DECLARE
    --TYPE R05_ID_TYPE IS TABLE OF R01_TABLE.R01_ID%TYPE;

     R01_IDS                       R05_ID_TYPE;
BEGIN
     SELECT R1.R01_ID AS R01_ID
     BULK COLLECT INTO R01_IDS
       FROM R01_TABLE R1,
            R05_TABLE R5
      WHERE R1.R01_ID = R5.R05_R01_ID_FK
            AND R5.R05_STATUS = 'D'
            AND R5.R05_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED <= TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 1095
            AND R1.R01_ID NOT IN (
                    SELECT R01.R01_ID
                      FROM R01_TABLE R01,
                           R05_TABLE R05
                     WHERE R05.R05_STATUS != 'D'
                           AND R01.R01_ID = R05.R05_R01_ID_FK);

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (R01_IDS.COUNT);

     FOR INDX IN 1 .. R01_IDS.COUNT
     LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (R01_IDS (INDX) );
          INSERT 
                INTO R01_TABLE_ARCHIVED
                     (R01_ID_TYPE,
                      R01_IDENTITY_NUMBER,
                      R01_PASSPORT_COUNTRY,
                      R01_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED)
               SELECT RR1_R01_ID_TYPE,
                      RR1_R01_IDENTITY_NUMBER,
                      RR1_R01_PASSPORT_COUNTRY,
                      RR1_R01_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED
                 FROM (SELECT R01_ID_TYPE,
                              R01_IDENTITY_NUMBER,
                              R01_PASSPORT_COUNTRY,
                              R01_DATE_TIME_CAPTURED
                         FROM R01_TABLE
                        --Using the collection in SQL statement
                        WHERE R01_ID IN (Select column_value from table(R01_IDS) );
     END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. When I execute the procedure as above, I am getting a compilation error as below Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"  | Error(47,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>  <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Comment: @sher17 Looks like you are executing both statement together. In that case put `/` after the first create statement and try

Comment: Also I am using Oracle 12C

Comment: of course adding a / after the first create statement solved the issue. Thank you very much for the guidance.